# Using same artifact in different projects, different transitive dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, jersey-client

I'm using the same artifact in two different projects, however I'm getting different versions of jersey dependencies that are causing me issues. How is it possible that a single artifact in the same versions contains different transitive dependencies in each project?

Project A:

```
 \- com.csg.rdx.base.orc:rdx-client:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
+- com.csg.rdx.base.public:javautils-micro:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
|  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.5.2:compile
|  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
|  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.26:compile
|  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlall:rdl-java-runtime:jar:1.0.1_0_1:compile
|  |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5.2:compile
|  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
|  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
|  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
|  +- com.csg.rdx.build:rdx-javautils-nano:jar:1.0.2_0_1:compile
|  +- com.csg.rdx.build:rdx-build-utils:jar:1.0.2_0_1:compile
|  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
+- com.csg.rdx.base.public:pki-rest-client:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
|  +- com.csg.rdx.base.public:pki-rest-client-micro:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
|  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.17:compile
|  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b10:compile
|  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b10:compile
|  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b10:compile
|  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b10:compile
|  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b10:compile
|  |  |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
|  |  +- com.csg.rdx.base.public:pki-wrapper:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
|  |  |  +- com.csg.rdx.base.public:pki-wrapper-micro:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
|  |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.26:compile
|  |  |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:runtime
|  |  |  +- au.com.bytecode:opencsv:jar:2.4:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-vfs2:jar:2.6.0:compile
|  |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs-client:jar:3.2.1:compile
|  |  |  |     +- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.7.5:compile
|  |  |  |     |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.6.0:compile
|  |  |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.9:compile
|  |  |  |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9:compile
|  |  |  |        \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.9:compile
|  |  |  \- com.csg.cs.aura.dis.agl:LarcsAdapter:jar:2.4.3:compile
|  |  +- com.csg.rdx.base.public:pki-wrapper-binder:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
|  |  |  +- com.csg.rdx.base.public:pki-wrapper-binder-pki-framework:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
|  |  |  +- com.csg.cs.tip.pki:keyonOCSPClient:jar:6.0.4:runtime
|  |  |  +- ch.keyon:jacapi-ase:jar:2.1:compile
|  |  |  \- ch.keyon:jacapi-interoperability:jar:2.1.1:compile
|  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0:compile
|  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.17:compile
|  +- org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:jar:2.17:compile
|  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.17:compile
|  |     +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
|  |     \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
|  \- org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-jetty-connector:jar:2.17:compile
|     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.1.1.v20140108:compile
|        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.1.1.v20140108:compile
|        |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.1.1.v20140108:compile
|        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.1.1.v20140108:compile
+- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.9:compile
|  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.11:compile
|  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
|  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
+- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.2:compile
+- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
+- com.csg.rdx.base.orc:rdx-rdl:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
|  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.Calc.Legacy-java:jar:1.0.1745:compile
|  |  \- com.csg.rdx.rdlcore:rdl-java-runtime:jar:1.0.91714:compile
|  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.Calc.Private-java:jar:1.0.1810:compile
|  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.Calc.Public-java:jar:1.0.1770:compile
|  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.DLF-java:jar:1.0.1747:compile
|  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.Interfaces-java:jar:1.0.1735:compile
|  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.RDF.Private-java:jar:1.0.1753:compile
|  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.RDF.Public-java:jar:1.0.1739:compile
|  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.RDF.Security-java:jar:1.0.1746:compile
|  \- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.RDL.Language-java:jar:1.0.1735:compile
+- com.csg.rdx.base.orc:rdx-client-interfaces:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
\- com.csg.rdx.base.orc:rdx-common-micro:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
   \- org.javatuples:javatuples:jar:1.2:compile
```

As you can see, all **jersey** libraries are in **2.17** version.

Project B:

```
 +- com.csg.rdx.base.orc:rdx-client:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
 |  +- com.csg.rdx.base.public:javautils-micro:jar:1.0.2_0_1:compile
 |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.5.2:compile
 |  |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
 |  |  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlall:rdl-java-runtime:jar:1.0.1_0_1:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
 |  |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
 |  |  +- com.csg.rdx.build:rdx-javautils-nano:jar:1.0.2_0_1:compile
 |  |  +- com.csg.rdx.build:rdx-build-utils:jar:1.0.2_0_1:compile
 |  |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
 |  +- com.csg.rdx.base.public:pki-rest-client:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
 |  |  +- com.csg.rdx.base.public:pki-rest-client-micro:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.29.1:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:jar:2.6.1:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.csg.rdx.base.public:pki-wrapper:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- com.csg.rdx.base.public:pki-wrapper-micro:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
 |  |  |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.30:compile
 |  |  |  |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:runtime
 |  |  |  |  +- au.com.bytecode:opencsv:jar:2.4:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-vfs2:jar:2.1:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- com.csg.cs.aura.dis.agl:LarcsAdapter:jar:2.4.3:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.csg.rdx.base.public:pki-wrapper-binder:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- com.csg.rdx.base.public:pki-wrapper-binder-pki-framework:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- com.csg.cs.tip.pki:keyonOCSPClient:jar:6.0.4:runtime
 |  |  |  |  +- ch.keyon:jacapi-ase:jar:2.1:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- ch.keyon:jacapi-interoperability:jar:2.1.1:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.17:compile
 |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:jar:2.29.1:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.29.1:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.3:compile
 |  |  |  \- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.6:compile
 |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-jetty-connector:jar:2.29.1:compile
 |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.27.v20200227:compile
 |  |        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.27.v20200227:compile
 |  |        |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.27.v20200227:compile
 |  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.27.v20200227:compile
|  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.12:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
|  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
|  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13:compile
|  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.12:compile
|  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
|  +- com.csg.rdx.base.orc:rdx-rdl:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
|  |  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.Calc.Legacy-java:jar:1.0.1745:compile
|  |  |  \- com.csg.rdx.rdlcore:rdl-java-runtime:jar:1.0.91714:compile
|  |  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.Calc.Private-java:jar:1.0.1810:compile
|  |  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.Calc.Public-java:jar:1.0.1770:compile
|  |  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.DLF-java:jar:1.0.1747:compile
|  |  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.Interfaces-java:jar:1.0.1735:compile
|  |  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.RDF.Private-java:jar:1.0.1753:compile
|  |  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.RDF.Public-java:jar:1.0.1739:compile
|  |  +- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.RDF.Security-java:jar:1.0.1746:compile
|  |  \- com.csg.rdx.rdlp.internal:RDx.RDL.Language-java:jar:1.0.1735:compile
|  +- com.csg.rdx.base.orc:rdx-client-interfaces:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
|  \- com.csg.rdx.base.orc:rdx-common-micro:jar:1.0.0_0_1:compile
|     \- org.javatuples:javatuples:jar:1.2:compile
```

Now, in this project, all jersey libraries are in version 2.29 and that is causing me problems. Any idea how is that possible?

Dependency **com.csg.rdx.base.orc:rdx-client:1.0.0_0_1** is the only one in both projects. It'defined in the dependencyManagement section of parent projects.

Unfortunately, due to company policy I cannot post entire poms/projects.

Comment: My assumption is simply that the project where your dependency is used defines a different version of jersey library...

Comment: Please post the complete dependency tree.